# insert new CSV data into sqlite data base

Tags: sqlite

I want to insert new data from a csv file into my database. I would appreciate if any one can help me with a "file.csv" looking like:

```
NO.        from        to        date
1          antony      bits      1/1/2000
2          bits        antony    1/2/2000
```

and the database has an additional column and looks like this

```
UNO        NO.        from        to        date
1          1          antony      bits      1/1/2000
2          3          mike        antony    1/1/2001
```

the result may probably look like:

```
UNO        NO.        from        to        date
1          1          antony      bits      1/1/2000
2          3          mike        antony    1/1/2001
3          2          bits        antony    1/2/2000
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

```
String[][] data;

// read csv into data

// first row is headers so omit;
for(int r = 1; r < data.length; r++) {

    // assuming your database table name is table1

    String updateQuery = "update table1 set from = '" + data[r][1] + "',  to = '" + data[r][2] + "', date = '" + data[r][3] + "' where NO. = '" + data[r][0] + "'";

    int updatedRowCount = executeUpdate(updateQuery);

    if(updatedRowCount == 0) {
        String insertQuery = "insert into table1 (UNO, NO., from, to, date) values ((select MAX(UNO)+1 FROM table1), '" + data[r][0] + "'" + data[r][1] + "'" + data[r][2] + "'" + data[r][3] + "')";
        executeUpdate(insertQuery);
    }

}
```

if you can not do this programmatically you can use update and insert sql's above